# Generating Print ready contents with WPF with paper precision

Tags: wpf, xaml, flowdocument, xpsdocument, fixeddocumentsequence

I am new to WPF and c# as a whole. I have experience from programming language like PHP, HTML and Javascript so I was able to cope quickly.

I have a project that is used to print PINs and Serial Number on a card. Let say the card is A4 and on the paper there are 4 rows and 3 columns of printed cards.

My problem is, I dont really know how to generate the dynamic document and the approach to use. Since the content is not that I have to just make it available on the paper before hand, it has to be placed on a particular position on the paper. Inches calculation will strictly be adhered to.

The link below illustrates an explanation of what I am talking about with border exclusive. All I want to generate is the PIN and serial in this way on a specific paper size.

http://ecloudpack.com/grid.png

Dont get me wrong, speaking of flowDocuments, I think I can bring out something  but I am faced with the challenge of precision of position on the paper and making sure the pagination is correct and making sure the margin as specified is what is generated.

I have a Monday deadline and I have been trying.

Is there anyone that can help.

Comment: Ok @Will, after much brainstorming and calculation, I was able to get the exactly what I need to do. Actually I used a flowDOcumentScrollViewer to achieve this. since you said my question is not clear and this discussion has been closed, I would have taken the time to explain my solution because I noticed alot of people has the same problem here on stackoverflow. it is about placing element on absolute position of a flowDocument and getting pagination right in WPF.

Although my code is amateur, if you permit me, I can share my simple solution.

Comment: If you could also [edit] your question to narrow down the scope, now that you understand it better, it would help.